# Reference Quasar CSS breakpoints in Vue expressions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, responsive-design, quasar-framework

I am utilising the QDialog component of Quasar Framework at present, and would like the `maximized` property value to be set based upon the current screen size ie. maximized for small screens only. Is there some variable I can reference in my component code or expressions for this purpose? Something along the lines of:

```
    <q-dialog v-model="showdialog" :maximized="myBreakpointVar === 'sm'"> ... </q-dialog>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [screen plugin](https://quasar.dev/options/screen-plugin) should do what you want:

```
<q-dialog v-model="showdialog" :maximized="$q.screen.sm"> ... </q-dialog>
```

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated!

Comment: If you want to use the actual size (eg: for the drawer's breakpoint, you can use `$q.screen.sizes.sm`)